# Invalid solutions to Piecewise Mccormick Envelope Implementation

Tags: optimization, c++, mccormick

I am currently trying to implement a piecewise McCormick envelope in [Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/) (c++). The current issue I am having is that the solution produced by the optimization does not produce a valid $x$ and $y$ values (outside my specified bounds or infeasible) and "$w$" is not close to $x*y$

I have used several references such as [A Global Quasi-Dynamic Model for Contact-Trajectory Optimization](http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss16/p047.pdf), [McCormick envelopes Northwestern Wiki](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes), and more, but I have based off the code below from [Mixed-Integer Convex Optimization for Planning Aggressive Motions of Legged Robots Over Rough Terrain](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Valenzuela16.pdf).

A few things that I felt were missing from this particular paper was the sum of the binary decision variable $z$ equal to 1. If I'm not mistaken, one piece of the piecewise McCormick envelope gets chosen by the optimization, thus, the sum of $z$ should be equal to 1.

Gurobi was used to solve this problem.

I would like to know if I am missing any major components to the piecewise McCormick envelope.

```
    solvers::MathematicalProgram prog = solvers::MathematicalProgram();

    // For this problem, M < 4 gives a solution. However, it may be incorrect. 
    // M >= 4 makes the problem infeasible 
    const int M = 6; //number of partitions

    solvers::VectorDecisionVariable<1> x = prog.NewContinuousVariables<1>("x"); 
    solvers::VectorDecisionVariable<1> y = prog.NewContinuousVariables<1>("y"); 
    solvers::VectorXDecisionVariable x_hat = prog.NewContinuousVariables(M, "x_hat");
    solvers::VectorXDecisionVariable y_hat = prog.NewContinuousVariables(M, "y_hat");
    solvers::VectorDecisionVariable<1> w = prog.NewContinuousVariables<1>("w"); 
    solvers::VectorXDecisionVariable z = prog.NewBinaryVariables(M, "z"); 
    //solvers::VectorDecisionVariable<1> lorentz = prog.NewContinuousVariables<1>("lorentz");

    const double x_upper = 1;
    const double x_lower = 0; 
 
    // Replacing quadratic cost with rotated lorentz cone in the future. (developer's suggesting for better results)
    // prog.AddLinearCost(lorentz[0]);
    // prog.AddRotatedLorentzConeConstraint(
    //   symbolic::Expression(lorentz[0]), symbolic::Expression(1), (0.4-w[0])*2*(0.4-w[0]) + (0.5-x[0])*10*(0.5-x[0])
    // );

    //Min 2*(0.4-w)^2 + 10*(0.5-x)^2   --> solution should be x:0.5, y:0.8, w:0.4
    prog.AddCost((0.4-w[0])*2*(0.4-w[0]) + (0.5-x[0])*10*(0.5-x[0]));  

    VectorXd x_bounds(M+1);
    x_bounds = VectorXd::Zero(M+1);

    // Generate evenly distributed upper and lower bounds
    for(int i = 0; i <= M; i++){
      x_bounds(i) = i*(x_upper-x_lower)/M + x_lower;
    }

    Expression e_x; //Sum of x_hat
    Expression e_y; //Sum of y_hat
    Expression e_z; //Sum of z

    Expression e_1;
    Expression e_2;
    Expression e_3;
    Expression e_4;

    for(int k = 0; k < M; k++){

      // Bound constraints for all x_hat and y_hat values
      prog.AddLinearConstraint(
        x_bounds(k)*z[k] <= x_hat[k] && x_hat[k] <= x_bounds(k+1)*z[k] && 
        0 <= y_hat[k] && y_hat[k] <= z[k]
      );
      // The constraint below has been removed.
      // y_bounds(k)*z[k] <= y_hat[k] && y_hat[k] <= y_bounds(k+1)*z[k]

      // Add sum of lower and upper bounds
      e_1 += x_bounds(k)*y_hat[k]; 
      e_2 += x_bounds(k+1)*y_hat[k] + x_hat[k] - x_bounds(k+1);
      e_3 += x_bounds(k)*y_hat[k] + x_hat[k] - x_bounds(k);
      e_4 += x_bounds(k+1)*y_hat[k];

      e_x += x_hat[k];  // e_x += x_hat[M-1]; The paper has capital M but I assumed that this is a mistake. 
      e_y += y_hat[k];  // e_y += y_hat[M-1]; 
      e_z += z[k];      //Sum of binary decision variable z 
    }

    prog.AddLinearConstraint(
      w[0] >= e_1 &&
      w[0] >= e_2 &&
      w[0] <= e_3 &&
      w[0] <= e_4 &&

      x[0] == e_x &&
      y[0] == e_y &&
      e_z == 1 
    );
```

Comment: Gurobi supports quadratic terms in the objective and in the constraints. I would try that first.

Comment: My goal is to approximate bilinear constraints as linear ones. So I would like to make this work instead of using a quadratic constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the `e_z == 1` constraint belongs in the model. Your constraints `y_bounds(k)*z[k] <= y_hat[k] && y_hat[k] <= y_bounds(k+1)*z[k]` do not appear in the Valenzuela dissertation, though, and I suspect they are the source of your troubles. Note, for example, that if $M=10$ and $z[3] = 1$, you are forcing $x\in [0.3, 0.4]$ **and** $y\in [0.3,0.4]$, the latter restriction for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have made changes to my program, however, it still gives me the same problems such as infeasible solution when M is a high number (e.g. 4,5,6...) and the solutions to x and y do not multiply to w. I have also added in the constraint 0 <= y_hat[k] <= z[k]

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to show the updated code, so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code.
I have also looked at the code again and I feel the problem has to do with these lines: 
      e_2 += x_bounds(k+1)*y_hat[k] + x_hat[k] - x_bounds(k+1);
      e_3 += x_bounds(k)*y_hat[k] + x_hat[k] - x_bounds(k);
I noticed that the last -x_bounds(k) terms get summed up even though this particular bound may not be chosen by z. However, this is what is written in the reference.

Comment: I think (4.22b) and (4.22c) in the dissertation are wrong. Besides leaving out parentheses, the summands should be multiplied by $z_m$, so that only one summand is nonzero. $z_m = 0 \implies \hat{u}_m = 0 = \hat{v}_m$, so only the last term in each of those constraints needs to be multiplied by $z_m$ to fix it.

Comment: I think this solved the problem. Thank you very much. Is there a specific place I should place the final code?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as the code goes, no, there's no specific place for it. If you would like to share it and have a blog, you could post it there. Otherwise, you could park it in any hosted repository where you have an account (GitHub, BitBucket, SourceForge, ...) or in a public folder in a cloud storage account you might have (Dropbox etc.) and just put the link here.